# How can I safely communicate with my remote data base in Zeos?

Tags: delphi, security, remote-access, delphi-xe3, zeos

I use MySQL in a shared server account and my worry is if a hacker monitors the connection between my application and that MySQL server.

Is that connection ciphered anyhow or is it raw data passing through (including at the connection time when Zeos `TZConnection` component informs the server what is the data base name, user name and password)?

If it's raw, how could I add some protection to it?

Comment: I mean that with local servers, I have to synchronize the local databases in all buildings between themselves. Using a single remote 24/7 server will deprecate this method. My concern is about communication security in that way.

Comment: You don't connect directly from your app to the database. You use https to connect your application to an application on the server, and that server application handles the interaction with the database. You can do research on https and Delphi via Google or Bing.

Comment: I have edited the question, the sync texts are irrelevant

Comment: @JanDoggen When I cited local synchronization I meant FireBird Clustering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is not your `TZConnection` which speaks with the server. Instead, it communicates with `libmysql.dll` which sends and receives data from the `Mysql server`.

To secure your connection to the server you can use `SSL`. You will need 3 certificates:

- CA-cert.pem
- client-cert.pem
- client-key.pem

You can find information on how to generate them in this [MySQL link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/creating-ssl-certs.html).

Once you have them you need to setup `TZConnection` to indicate `SSL`should be used as follows:

```
Connection.Properties.Values['MYSQL_SSL']      := 'TRUE';
Connection.Properties.Values['MYSQL_SSL_CA']   := 'c:/MyPath/CA-cert.pem';
Connection.Properties.Values['MYSQL_SSL_CERT'] := 'c:/MyPath/client-cert.pem';
Connection.Properties.Values['MYSQL_SSL_KEY']  := 'c:/MyPath/client-key.pem';
```

More information about MySql and SSL can be found in this [discussion](http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=3033) in Zeos forums.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use non obvious names for those 3 files?

Comment: @EASI, as far as I know you can change the name of the 3 files, but never tried it myself. Regarding pointing certificate files on the web that is something I do not know. I would try to ask it in a new question with `MySQL` tag, since it is something that has nothing to do with Delphi or Zeos.